Azure Automation custom module not exporting commands as expected
I'm having the same exact issue as described here:
Azure Automation Custom Module not Exporting Commands
I had the Export-ModuleMember in my psm1 file and have FunctionsToExport set to "*". The functions are being exported locally but when I upload to AA, nothing is exported. This was working for several years now. I updated one function earlier and when I try uploading to AA to update the module, it now doesn't export any of the functions.
Any other ideas?
I tried removing Export-ModuleMmeber from my psm1 file as suggested in that previous thread but did not really make any difference.

Your method seems correct to me, and the solution provided for a similar issue on SO appears to address your problem effectively.
Need to check below:

Check the .psm1 and .psd1 file paths are appropriately given.
Consider specifying the names of the functions you wish to export directly within the .psd1 file.
Make sure to check if all the necessary dependency modules are also working properly.
After making necessary changes, zip the entire module folder again before uploading it to the Azure Automation.

If still the issue persists, clear the cache and create a new module with the updated functions and then upload it to the Azure Automation.
I tried to create a sample module with a short function script, and it worked as below.

Reference: MSDoc, Manage modules

What do you exactly mean by "Check the .psm1 and .psd1 file paths are appropriately given."? FWIW, here is the psm1 file:
https://imgur.com/vXy5ALL
And here is the psd1 file:
https://imgur.com/w6H0lS1
https://imgur.com/wNxDNQw
Why can I not just put * (asterisk) in the psd1 file for FunctionsToExport? I don't really care about performance.
I don't really have any dependency modules in there.
I already tried clearing the broswer cache and using another browser, same issue. This module works fine when I import it locally, like in your example.

Still the same issue is coming? @kevindd992002
